# Is there any way to delete inbox email in outlook by using officeJS Add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is there any way to delete inbox email in outlook by using officeJS Add-in?

Solution approach for implementing delete functionality for inbox email in outlook by using officeJS Add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Web add-ins work under the context of currently selected/opened item in Outlook. It is not designed to delete or create items - you will not find any methods for that in the Office JavaScript API. Instead, you may consider using *Graph API* or *EWS*, see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for more information.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.